# User control set in web.config works but shows as warning on web page with no intellisense

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, web-config

I have a user control that i set on the web.config because it'll be used on multiple pages.
This works on the pages that use the user control but it shows up on the webpage as errors with the green swiggly line and hence intellisense doesn't work.

This is how it looks like in the web.config:
[image]

This is how it looks like in the code behind with the error message when I hover over the green swiggly:

[image]

I read that it may be corrected by clearing the related schemas directory but that didn't work.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes i get the same warnings and after building, or running the app it will go away.

Other times i have to close the application and reopen VS